# QTabWidget - How do I edit each widget separately?

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

I am in the process of learning Qt and generally C++, and I am stuck on this problem. Hopefully, it will be simple to answer.

I have a `QTextEdit` created by this code:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionNewtab_triggered()
{
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(new QTextEdit, "Untitled Document");
}
```

Now, if I make three tabs, I'm not sure how to edit the `QTextBox` of the current tab that is selected. I looked in the documentation (which is pretty good) and I think I need [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#currentWidget), but I'm not sure how. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678684/access-the-widget-of-a-tab-in-a-qtabwidget) on this site, but that seems to edit all `QTextEdits`?

The answer is probably extremely simple and I'm just missing something :). Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acess the text edit directly with this:

`qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget())->SetText("my text");`

Answer (score 1):

Save pointer to your desired `QTextBox` and edit it as you wish.

```
QTextEdit *myTextEdit;

void MainWindow::on_actionNewtab_triggered()
{
    myTextEdit = new QTextEdit;
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(myTextEdit, "Untitled Document");
}
```

You may also use [`QTabWidget::widget()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#widget) and [`QTabWidget::currentWidget()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#currentWidget) to get pointer to your widget after creation, but you have to cast the result to actual type first.